# What's the name and use of "@" operator in MySql?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am a novice programmer and I'm currently working with functions and stored procedures in MySQL using Workbench 5.6 . I've been searching for some time now here on SO and on the Web for a formal definition of the "@" operator in MySQL and it's proper use, but I wasn't able to find some concrete explanation.

Let's say that I have this :

```
 /*..... Stored Procedure... */

 declare i int ;
 set @i = 1 ;
 select @i ;

 /* do some other stuff */
 End;
```

The result of select will be 1 ,instead, if I do:

```
 select i ;
```

I will get a Null result.
From my intuition so far, I think that is accessing the direction in the memory of a stored variable  and prints/modifies its content,still I'm not quite sure.Could you shed some more light?
Are there any other uses of it?

Thanks a priori.

Comment: What part of the [MySQL Reference Manual section on the topic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) didn't you understand?

Comment: @EJP - He possibly couldn't find it searching by `@` or `at operator` (I've tried and it wouldn't show up) and never related it to `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an operator (I suspect you come from PHP, where it *is* an operator). It's the syntax for [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables are written as `@var_name`, where the variable name
>   var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, “.”, “_”, and “$”. A
>   user variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a
>   string or identifier (for example, `@'my-var'`, `@"my-var"`, or
>   @`my-var`).

Answer (score 0):

The @ denotes a variable, you prefix your variables with the @ to prevent confusing them with column names and other schema, it also makes life a lot easier when looking at code. When you enter select I from x;, your looking for column I, which doesn't exist in the table, hence the null.